# How to check if row exists before SELECT INTO statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm using Oracle SQL and have a procedure that is doing some operations on tables. During the procedure there is a "SELECT x INTO y FROM TABLE z WHERE..." statement inside a loop. Unfortunatly during the procedure I can't guarante that there is always a row to the corresponding where condition because it changes dynamically.
Is it possible to check if a row exists before the statement? I was thinking of sth like "if exists(select ...) then SELECT X INTO y..."

Thanks for the help!
Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's no point in checking it first, and re-using the same statement again.

You could handle the exception (possibly in an inner `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block):

```
declare
  y number;
begin
  begin               --> inner block starts here
    select x into y from z where ...

    insert into ...
  exception
    -- handle it, somehow; I chose not to do anything
    when no_data_found then
      null;
  end;               --> inner block ends here
end;
```

---

Or, if you used cursor `FOR` loop, you wouldn't have to handle it because - if `select` returns `x`, `insert` would run. Otherwise, nothing in that loop would ever be executed:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select x from z where ...) loop
    insert into ...
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

An exception handler as in Littlefoot's answer is the most correct and explicit approach, however just for completeness you might also consider using an aggregate.

Value 'X' exists in the table:

```
declare
    p_someparam varchar2(1) := 'X';
    l_somevalue varchar2(1);
    l_check     number;
begin
    select max(dummy), count(*) into l_somevalue, l_check
    from   dual d
    where  d.dummy = p_someparam;

    dbms_output.put_line('Result: '||l_somevalue); 
    dbms_output.put_line(l_check||' row(s) found'); 
end;
```

```
Result: X
1 row(s) found
```

Value 'Z' does not exist in the table:

```
declare
    p_someparam varchar2(1) := 'Z';
    l_somevalue varchar2(1);
    l_check     number;
begin
    select max(dummy), count(*) into l_somevalue, l_check
    from   dual d
    where  d.dummy = p_someparam;

    dbms_output.put_line('Result: '||l_somevalue); 
    dbms_output.put_line(l_check||' row(s) found'); 
end;
```

```
Result: 
0 row(s) found
```

You can add logic to handle the cases where the count check is 0 or greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having  procedure then I should say use if statement and then write the sql:

```
select some_column into some_variable from tablename where condition 

IF somevariable not in (<list of values separated by comma>)THEN
   {statements to execute }
END IF;
```